# Magento2 Add additional js files to home page only

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to add additional javascript files to just the home page in Magento 2?

---

The current code works. However the files are placed on every page which is not needed.

### Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
        <link src="js/sample.js"/>
    </head> 
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

`app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

```
   <head>
    <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
    <link src="js/sample.js"/>
   </head>
```